# Check if all commits to one GIT branch have been cherry picked to another

Tags: git, version-control, branch, gerrit, cherry-pick

Is there some way, maybe using git log, that I can see if any of my commits in "develop" have not been cherry-picked to "otherbranch" yet?

For example I make 6 commits to develop, and cherry-pick 5 of them to otherbranch. What git log command could I execute to output the 1 commit I missed?

(All our commits are pushed through Gerrit, so any Gerrit based solutions would help too.)

Answer (score 8):

```
git log --cherry otherbranch...develop
```

should do it.

Log options `--cherry-mark`, `--left-only`, `--right-only`, `--cherry` and `--cherry-pick` that show various selections of similar or dissimilar commits on a `...` (two-branch aka "symmetric difference") log. Also, `--left-right` shows for each commit whether its changes appear only on the left branch, right branch, or both.

Comment: Cherry-pick makes a new commit that applies the same changes.  You're seeing the original commit and the cherry-picked commit.

Comment: So If I make 6 commits to develop, and cherry-pick 5 of those commits to otherbranch, I'd expect there to be a git log command that outputs the 1 commit. What would that be?

Comment: `git log --right-only otherbranch...develop`, I think.  Try `git help log`.

Comment: Besides `--cherry` (which is a synonym for `--right-only --cherry-mark --no-merges` you can use `--right-only --cherry-pick --no-merges`. The difference is that `--cherry-mark` *marks* the commits (as equivalent or not), while `--cherry-pick` *skips* the equivalent commits. The `git cherry` command is like similar, although I prefer the direct symmetric difference for instruction purposes: `git cherry` is what you use *after* you know all the above. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Since some commits from `develop` branch cherry-pick to `otherbranch`, the commit id will be different. If you use `git log --cherry otherbranch..develop`, you will see all the commits which exist in `develop` branch (including the commits cherry-pich to `otherbranch`).

If your **commit comments are unique**, you can search the commits cherry-pick to `otherbranch` by

```
git log develop..otherbranch --grep=comment1 --grep=comment2 --grep=comment3 --grep=comment4 --grep=comment5 --grep=comment6 --oneline
```

So the commits which are not cherry-pick to `otherbranch` is opposite.